# Can't Call Method of Custom Class Object Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, class, methods

I'm in the middle of writing some code for scheduling automation. I am relatively new to VBA programming but have been programming in other languages for years. For my project I've created a class called OpsFloor which is supposed to simulate the operations floor. I'm parsing user information into an array and trying to pass that array (I've tried both passing the whole array and by individual values) into an instance of the OpsFloor object. I'm worried I have some fundamental misunderstanding about how classes work in VBA. Below is the sub from within the Class

```
Public Sub SetProcessMatrixValue(x As Integer, y As Integer, value As Integer)
    ProcessMatrix(x, y) = value
End Sub
```

Here is the call from within the worksheet object sub in Excel:

```
Option Explicit
Private OperationMatrix(18, 8) As Integer
Private dailyWF As New OpsFloor
Public Sub StartingWorksheet()
...
dailyWF.SetProcessMatrixValue 0, 0, 30
End Sub
```

When I try to run the sub to assign those values to the class instance through the SetProcessMatrixValue method I get Run-time Error '438' Object Doesn't Support this property or method.

Comment: Sorry for being a noob but I'm not sure where you got that code from.

Comment: sorry, that was my code :)  Is it happening on this `dailyWF.SetProcessMatrixValue 0, 0, 30` line

Comment: I actually figured it out. My class wasn't properly instantiating because of an error in the constructor code, but because I used the `Private dailyWF As New OpsFloor` instead of `Dim dailyWF As OpsFloor:Set dailyWF = New OpsFloor` Once I switched it it pointed me to the error within the constructor (unnecessary parenthesis when adding to a collection) and now it runs perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

So I had a couple issues which I managed to uncover after piecing together a lot of different posts.

Firstly the way I originally declared my class variable:

```
Private dailyWF As New OpsFloor
```

This didn't properly instantiate the class object. When I tried to change it to the following:

```
Private dailyWF As New OpsFloor
Set dailyWf = New Operations_Floor
```

I got an error which pointed me to the class constructor. It ended up being an issue with how I was assigning objects to a collection.

```
newCollection.Add(new Object) //WRONG!
newCollection.Add new Object //Right!
```

For other newbs like me I found a post that recommended turning on "Break in Class Modules" by going to Tools>Options>General>Break in Class Modules. This showed me the error was inside the class constructor and not actually an issue with the way I was making my call.

Comment: "Break in Class Modules" just save me hour I'm sure. Thanks